How do I modify my application to accommodate a Dagger @Provides method that now needs to accept runtime parameters?
I've got a @Provides method that instantiates a dependency client like:
@Provides
@Singleton
public DependencyServiceClient providesDependencyServiceClient() {
   return new ClientBuilder()
      .remoteOf(DependencyServiceClient.class)
      .newClient();
}

This is then also provided up in a chain to other @Provides methods. Now, I need to customize the configuration of this based on some variables known at runtime, something to the effect of:
@Provides
@Singleton
public DependencyServiceClient providesDependencyServiceClient(String runtimeConfiguration) {
   return new ClientBuilder()
      .remoteOf(DependencyServiceClient.class)
      .withConfig(runtimeConfiguration)
      .newClient();
}

Anyone have any tips on how to achieve this?
I have looked into using @AssistedInject with @AssistedFactory but couldn't figure out how to get things working.

Your technique of injecting the configuration seems pretty good; I'd written up a similar answer for which injecting the configuration in this way was the eventual recommendation. What kind of tips are you looking for? Is there a particular problem with this approach that you're trying to solve? (Your mention of AssistedInject suggests that to create your Client you need to mix the runtimeConfiguration with deps from your graph, but if you have a ClientBuilder as you described, then the best you can do is inject them as parameters yourself.)
